# What's wrong in $\int_{-2}^1 x^3dx=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^4 udu$

Tags: real-analysis

What's wrong in $$\int_{-2}^1 x^3\mathrm dx=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^4 u\mathrm du \ ?$$

I set $u=x^2$, therefore $du=2xdx$. But when $x$ traverse $[-2,1]$, then $u$ traverse $[0,4]$ and thus 
$$\int_{-2}^1 x^3\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{4}^0 u\mathrm du=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^4 u\mathrm du.$$

But $\int_{)2}^1 x^3 \mathrm dx=-\frac{15}{4}$ whereas $-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^4u\mathrm du=-4$, therefore something is wrong here, but I don't see what's wrong...

Comment: when x=1, $u = (1)^2 = 1$  not 0

Comment: why donwvoted ?

Comment: @Rick I actually up-voted you at the beginning, so the down-vote was not from me.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can see the problem differently. The best thing is to see what happen we you set $u(x)=x^2$. Therefore $x^3= \frac{1}{2}u(x)u'(x)$ and you know that an antiderivative of a function of type $\frac{1}{2}u(x)u'(x)$ is $\frac{u^2(x)}{4}$.

Since $u(x)=x^2$, you get that the antiderivatives of $x^3$ is $\frac{x^4}{4},$
and thus 
$$\int_{-2}^1 x^3dx=[\frac{x^4}{4}]_{-2}^1=[\frac{u^2(x)}{4}]_{-2}^{1}=\frac{u^2(1)}{4}-\frac{u^2(-2)}{4}=[\frac{y^2}{4}]_{u(1)}^{u(-2)}=\int_{u(1)}^{u(-2)}\frac{y}{2}dy$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_4^1\frac{y}{2}dy=\int_{1}^{4}-\frac{y}{2}dy=-\frac{1}{2}\int_1^4 ydy.$$

Comment: Ok, that works. But not as a carefully described substitution, but by identifying an anti-derivative. And thus it is a solution to the original task, but not to the question on manipulating the integration intervals while changing the parametrisation.

Comment: I'm sorry but something look strange to me, me we set $u=x^2$, when $x$ traverse $[-2,1]$, $u$ traverse $[0,4]$ therefore why the limits are not $[0,4]$ ?

Comment: Yes and no. When $x$ traverse $[-2,-1]$, $u$ traverse $[4,1]$, then when x traverse $[-1,0]$, $u$ traverse $[1,0]$, and finally when $x$ traverse $[0,1]$, $u$ traverse $[0,1]$, therefore if you separate the cases, you get that $$...=\int_{4}^1 \frac{u}{2}du+\underbrace{\int_1^0 \frac{u}{2}du+\int_0^1\frac{u}{2}du}_{=0}=\int_{4}^1\frac{u}{2}du=-\int_1^4 \frac{u}{2}du.$$ Is it more clear ?

Answer (score 0):

Its your limits where you have made the mistake:
$$\int_{-2}^1 x^3\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{4}^{\color{red}{0}} u\mathrm du$$

The part marked red should be 1

Comment: why they are wrong ?

Comment: @Rick i'll show you

Comment: @Rick Take a closer look, I promise you it's 1 and not 0

Comment: For the reason I exposed in Amir answer, It's totally not logical... But anyway...

Comment: As huangqinjin explained, you need bijectivity in the substitution function. Or you need to count signed multiplicities of the values of the substitution. In this sense, the answer is not even wrong.

Comment: @LutzL: You don't need bijectivity at all !

Comment: Yes, you need bijectivity. By the false reasoning present here, $0=\int_{-1}^1 x\,dx=\int_0^1\,du=1$.

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood the [Variable Substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) of integration!

While substituting $ u $ for $ x $, we need a continuously differentiable function $\varphi: I_u \to I_x $, where $ I_u = [0,4],I_x=[-2,1] $ in your case. Or, if there exists $ \phi:I_x\to I_u $, and it's inverse $ \phi^{-1} $ is continuously differentiable, then $ \phi^{-1} $ can be the $ \varphi $.

$ u=\phi(x)=x^2 $ doesn't have inverse on the whole $ [-2,1] $, so you are wrong. But it does on $ [-2,0] $ and $ [0,1] $ respectively, namely $ -\sqrt{u} $ and $ \sqrt{u} $. So the following is correct:

$$ \int_{-2}^1 x^3\mathrm dx = \int_{-2}^0 x^3\mathrm dx + \int_{0}^1 x^3\mathrm dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{4}^0 u\mathrm du + \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^1 u\mathrm du = \frac{1}{2}\int_{4}^1 u\mathrm du $$

Comment: "$ u=\phi(x)=x^2 $ doesn't have inverse on the whole $ [-2,1] $, so you are wrong." This is not a problem ! $\varphi$ doesn't need to be bijective at all.

Comment: @Surb You are right, but we need $ \varphi $ from $ \phi $.

Comment: As I said, then you need to  count signed or oriented multiplicities. The value $u=0.5$ for instance occurs twice, once with sign $-1$ and once with sign $1$, thus with total multiplicity $0$.

Comment: @LutzL: You don't need bijectivity when the integrand is continuous, according to Newton-Leibniz .

Comment: But still you have to care for the orientation resp. signs of the integrals over the partial intervals. If not, you risk to calculate that $0=1$.

Comment: Where you really do not need bijectivity is when you reduce the problem to the fundamental theorem and just plug in the anti-derivative. This is what implicitely happens in your last line of computations.

Comment: @LutzLL: I know your viewpoint, substitutions need diffeomorphism. So $ \frac{1}{2}\int_{4}^0 u\mathrm du $ should be $ -\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^4 u\mathrm du $. But it's the special case - 1-dimensional definite integral. So there could be something more,such as the fundamental theorem. I think your viewpoint is more appropriate to higher dimensions and coordinate transformations.

Answer (score -1):

If $g:[a,b]\to [c,d]$ is a continuously differentiable function such that $g(a)=c$ and $g(b)=d$ or vice-versa(the orientation is taken care by the sign of the derivative, which does not happen in higher dimensions), then $\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f=\int_a^b (f\circ g)g'$.

Just by above,we let $g:[-2,1]\to [1,4]$ and $f(x)=x$, then $\int_{-2}^1x^3=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-2}^1 (x^2)(2x)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{(-2)^2}^{1^2} u=\frac{1}{2}\int_4^1 u$.

Comment: You did not include bijectivity in the necessary conditions for the substitution. Thus your result is wrong.

Comment: @LutzL: No, you don't need bijectivity.

Comment: Yes, you need to identify arcs where the relation between $u$ and $x$ is 1-to-1.

Comment: You can not call it a substitution if it is not bijective (diffeomorph). But you still can use the fundamental theorem. But then you can also go the full step and use $F(x)=x^4/4$ with $F'(x)=x^3$ to get the integral value as $F(1)-F(-2)=F(1)-F(2)$.

Answer (score -2):

$u=x^2$,  if $x \in [-2,1]$ then $u \in [4,1]$.

the rest is OK.

Comment: No, when $x\in[-2,1]$, then $x^2\in[0,4]$. Just make a draw. For example, $0\in [-2,1]$ and $0^2=0\in [0,4]$ but $0\notin [1,4]$...

Comment: in variable change we don't say $x \in [-2,1] \rightarrow x^2 \in [0,4] $ . i.e., we don't compute the range of $u=x^2$. we just compute the value of limits. $x_l=-2 \rightarrow u_l = 4$ and $x_h=1 \rightarrow = u_h = 1$.

Comment: It should have a reason... what is the reason ?

Comment: @Rick the reason is because of your substitution $u=x^2$ so $u_1=2^2=4$ and $u_2=1^2=1$. That's all there is to it.

Comment: And because of the substitution $u=x^2$ not being bijective on $[-2,1]$ this is not the answer to the question.